# Get a list of available components

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm writing an admin tool for a ColdFusion app, and I'd like to provide an autocomplete feature for a field for entering component names. In order to do this, I'd need a list of all of the components in the application. I have the following code to get a list of mappings:

```
public function getComponentNames() {
    var ServiceFactory = CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory');
    return ServiceFactory.runtimeService.getMappings();
}
```

Is there any better way to get a list of components than crawling the filesystem looking for .cfc files under these paths?

EDIT: This is currently working, but *painfully* slowly for just a couple of thousand components:

```
public function getComponents() {
    var ServiceFactory = CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory');
    var mappings = ServiceFactory.runtimeService.getMappings();

    for (m in mappings) {
        var components = DirectoryList(mappings[m], true, 'path', '*.cfc');
        writeDump(components);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always store those function results in a database which you refresh with a scheduled job.

Comment: You have an application with "a couple thousand components" ?

Comment: Yes. Yes, I do. This is why autocomplete would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

In CFML the sense of an "application" is pretty loose. It's more a bunch of files that interact with each other.

As well as scanning all the mappings, you'd also need to scan any directories within the subdirectory structure of the site as well.

Are you not better off - perhaps - writing an extension for Sublime Text or Eclipse or something? You can then leverage their idea of "projects", and you can let the IDE handle the file indexing. You can then just "do stuff" with the file listing the IDE will expose to you via the API. I've never written an IDE extension, so can't be more "helpful" than that, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm writing a page to test remote method calls for debugging purposes. I want to be able to call any remote method with user-supplied arguments and display the results. It would be very convenient to have a list of components for autocomplete, but I may simply have to do without.